# TexStudio Editor Background color in Mac

Tags: texstudio, mac

I am using Mac laptop with dark theme. TexStudio also shows in dark theme. I would like to change the editor background to

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Otherwise have you tried something like: Option->configure TeXstudio->SyntaxHighlight->Background

Comment: Option->configure TeXstudio->SyntaxHighlight->Background worked for me. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Actually , in Mac when I changed the theme to dark background, closed and opened TexStudio, the background shows black again. In Syntax highlighting, background color is still white. Any other way ??

Answer (score 1):

In TeXstudio you can change the background of the editor using: Option->configure TeXstudio->SyntaxHighlight->Background

And by save the configuration it should remain still way even after closing and reopening the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too, and a workaround can be found on the gitbuh community-pages here: [Workaround for TexStudio DarkMode exclusion MacOS](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/848#issuecomment-605485100)
In short, use this command in the terminal to exclude TexStudio from DarkMode:

```
defaults write texstudio NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

and this one to revert:

```
defaults delete texstudio NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance
```

Hope this helps.